# DomEvent .AddHandler/UpdatePanel with Stored Procedure error

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, updatepanel

The following error has been noted with asp.net applications and the use of ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender.

`Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.`

But I have one problem. I don't use the ModalPopupExtender. This just started happening when I implemented stored procedures to handle my CRUD operations. So, is this a known issue with UpdatePanel?

At this point am I best off eliminating the UpdatePanel and making use of jQuery to eliminate some postback? I'm sure there's a fix, like there is for the ModalPopupExtender (if you use it) but I'm discovering new errors with UpdatePanel (even though it is quite good/easy when used properly). A bit torn here...